# Android: Line break not working in text from plist(XML) file

Tags: android, string, android-layout, xml-parsing, textview

I'm creating a view that displays data that is parsed from a plist (XML) file.  My parsing routine stores the data as an Object in a hashmap that I later retrieve with a key. My textview does display the data, but it does not process the \n into line breaks. Instead, the \n displays along with the text.  Here is the code I use to retrieve my data from the hashmap:

```
String contactData = dict.get("Data").toString();
```

I have tried variations without success:

```
Object obj =  dict.get("Data");
String contactData = obj.toString();
and
contactData = (String)dict.get("Data");
```

My text is lengthy with \n imbedded to force line breaks. I set my text as follows:

```
TextView data = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.data);
data.setText(contactData);
```

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/light_grey"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/midnight_blue"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/midnight_blue"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/midnight_blue"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp" 
    android:text="Line one\nLine two\nLine3"/>
```

\n works fine if I hard code the text to my variable (contactData) or I use the default text in the layout XML file.  It does not work when I convert my object data toString??

Please do not suggest converting to \r\n.  \n is the line separator. I've gone down that line in a previous question and it wasn't the resolution.  The following code returns \n:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

My problem is related to how I'm retrieving my text from the hashmap and converting it to String.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated!!!

*** Update
Here is my parse routine for the plist file:

```
    public void parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    final XmlPullParserFactory xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    final XmlPullParser parser = xppf.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(inputStream, null);

    final Stack<List<Map<String, Object>>> arrayStack = new Stack<List<Map<String, Object>>>();
    final Stack<Map<String, Object>> dictStack = new Stack<Map<String, Object>>();
    final Stack<String> keyStack = new Stack<String>();

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        final String name = parser.getName();
        switch (eventType) {
        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            if ("array".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final List<Map<String, Object>> array = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
                arrayStack.push(array);
            } else if ("dict".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                dictStack.push(dict);
            } else if ("key".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                keyStack.push(parser.nextText()); // assign current key
            } else if ("string".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = dictStack.peek();
                final String string = parser.nextText();
                final String key = keyStack.pop();
                dict.put(key, string);
            } else if ("integer".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = dictStack.peek();
                final String integerStr = parser.nextText();
                final Integer integer = new Integer(integerStr);
                final String key = keyStack.pop();
                dict.put(key, integer);
            }  else if ("false".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = dictStack.peek();
                final Boolean booleanValue = new Boolean(false);
                final String key = keyStack.pop();
                dict.put(key, booleanValue);
            } else if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = dictStack.peek();
                final Boolean booleanValue = new Boolean(true);
                final String key = keyStack.pop();
                dict.put(key, booleanValue);
            }

            break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            if ("array".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final List<Map<String, Object>> array = arrayStack.pop();
                if (arrayStack.isEmpty()) {
                    // return array;
                    mPlistHashMap.put("array",array);
                    break;
                }
                // If not end of array, means it's an array within a dict
                final String key = keyStack.pop();
                dictStack.peek().put(key, array);
            } else if ("dict".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                final Map<String, Object> dict = dictStack.pop();
                if (!arrayStack.empty())
                    arrayStack.peek().add(dict);
                else
                    mPlistHashMap = dict;
            }
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
            done = true;
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

}
```

My plist consists of an Array of Dictionary items with three strings. Here is a snippet of my plist XML file:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>Mexico</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Mexico City</string>
        <key>Data</key>
        <string>Line one\nLine two\nLine three</string>
    </dict>
```

Comment: And XML file is definitely not a plist file :) Show the 'data' class code and how it's `toString()` is definied.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. FYI, on Mac and iOS, plist are stored as an XML file.  I use XMLPullParser to retrieve my data from the plist. I've posted my parsing routine. I do not have any problem retrieving my data.  I'm just having problems with \n codes imbedded into my text.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you are using an Android XML resource file and calling it 'plist'. The cause of this would be that your newlines are somehow getting escaped. What is the value of `contactData` as seen in the debugger? Also how does the relevant XML file part look like.

Comment: I know, it confusing when talking about XML data files and people are thinking layout XML files!! ;-D   Anyway, looking at my String variable in debug, there seems be an extra \ in the text.  It is not in the raw data, but it is somehow getting inserted during the parse. It looks like this:    "Line one\\nLine two\\nLine three"

Comment: Wrap your text in `<![CDATA[ ]]>` and use actual newlines.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean??  Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text in  and use actual newlines. Then the parser should give you the data exactly as written. Something like:

```
   <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Country</key>
            <string>Mexico</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Mexico City</string>
            <key>Data</key>
            <string>
<![CDATA[
Line one
Line two
Line three
]]>
            </string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: That fixes the line wrap issue, but the tags are being displayed.
<![CDATA[ and ]]>

Comment: You need to handle `CDSECT` and use `getText()` to get the actual text inside. See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#nextToken()

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to solve my problem by replacing the \\n with \n.

Comment: Of course that works, but it's essentially a hack. CDATA is the proper way to do it, and will also perform better, especially with larger texts.

Comment: I'm porting my app from iOS to android and would like both apps to share the same data files for continuity. The main data is store in a SQLite database and there wasn't any issue there.  I had a some data that seemed to fit well with the Property List structure when I was developing the iOS version.  One file has about 130 records each with 6-8 long text fields with embedded line breaks.  My final solution may very well be a hack or kludge, but I have the results I need without breaking the continuity of shared data with my iOS version.

Comment: FWIW, I'm doing a true port of my app utilizing the Android UI including ActionBar and Fragments. I am not making the Android version look just like the iOS version.  Thanks again for your help and I'll keep CDATA in mind for the future when I don't have the compatibility issues.

Comment: I see. There probably is some parser switch/setting(s) that lets you get the same behaviour in both OSes but I wouldn't know anything about iOS. XML is a standard after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nikolay's suggestions, I discovered that my text was somehow embedding and extra backslash to my line break character.  So my text had "\n" instead of "\n". I had tried using .replaceAll("\n","\n"), but for some reason that was not working.  Here is the code that worked for me:

```
contactData = dict.get("Data").toString().replace("\\n", "\n");
```